# Kentico - Different transformations for hero banners

Tags: kentico

I've set up a custom page type for my hero banners (all are inside /hero/ folder on the content tree) and used a repeater to display the banners in form of a carousel. The current transformation I have centering all elements (text/buttons) inside all banners. However, in some situation, it looks better if the elements are left or right aligned. Is there a way to use more than one transformations for this kind of thing; even better, is it possible to manually specify which transformation will be applied to which item inside the /hero/ folder.

I noticed there's a field for *Alternating transformation*; however, looks like Kentico will automatically apply it to the even items. Thanks for your input!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably the easiest way would be to add an extra field (or a couple of fiedls) to a page type, where editor could specify the position of elements or simply type in a class. E.g. drop down with otions right, left and center; each option value could be a class that you just include into your transformation. The rest is just implementation of appropriate CSS classes.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using **Text/XML** transformation then you could also write your inline if conditions like this:

```
{% if(heroName == "Zeus" || heroName == "Odin"){ %}
<h2>HTML for zeus or odin</h2>
{% } else { %}
<h2>HTML for anyone else </h2>
{% }%}
```

[This documentation](https://docs.kentico.com/display/K9/Macro+syntax) might be helpful with regards to macro syntax and expressions.

Answer (score 0):

Alternating transformation is used for automatic Odd/Even elements.

In you transofrmation you can use condition and call another transformation. Something like this:

```
{% CurrentDocument.ApplyTransformation( ([YOURCONDITION] ? "[TRANSFORMATION_A]" : "[TRANFORMATION_B]") ) %}
```

where [YOURCONDITION] is the condition to test if use TRANSFORMATION_A or TRANSFORMATION_B.
The transformation name must contain the entire "path" (example CMS.Root.UsersInText)

Comment: I'm not sure how to get entire path of the transformation. Is it something like below? ~/App_Themes/Components/Transformations/site.transformations/herobanner

Comment: nope. It's the "namespace" of the transformations. For example if the Transformation "MyTransformation" is in the Page Type "CUSTOM.Transformations", the complete name is: CUSTOM.Transformations.MyTransformation
Remember that the class where you call the ApplyTransformation method will "passed" to the transformation so for example if you use CurrentDocument.ApplyTransformation("CUSTOM.Transformations.MyTransformation") in MyTransformation you can access to all property of CurrentDocument (like AliasPath)